# How to get json data using REST API for on-premise TFS

Tags: json, tfs, postman

We have on-premise TFS Version 15.105.25910.0 i.e TFS 2017 and I am trying to get JSON data (let's say for a given Work Item id). I am using Postman to send/receive request.
 I was having an issue with permission denied then figured out a way to pass Personal access tokens in the request. 

Our basic TFS Url looks like this:

`http://tfs.blahblah.org:8080/TFS/MyOrgName/Software%20Group`

How to correctly get JSON data?

Reference material used:

- [Reference 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-4.1)
- [Reference 2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4bc3c905-ce10-4051-8bf2-34ca5cd513fd/how-to-get-work-items-using-rest-api-having-onpremise-tfs-2015?forum=tfsworkitemtracking)

Currently I am getting 200 OK status but the content type is HTML which says Javascript is Disabled. Not sure where the problem is occuring?

Feel free to ask more info if needed.

[image]

Comment: What API endpoint are you calling? If you're already authenticated using Windows authentication (which should be the case for an on-prem TFS installation), you don't need to use a PAT for this.

Comment: GET... We have user authentication set to **Prompt for username and password** so i need to provide PAT for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are using TFS 2017 RTM version, it's suggested to upgrade to the latest **Update 3.1** edition.

Then, please check your Postman's version, make sure you are using the latest version **v6.1.4**. You could download the latest version from website below: https://www.getpostman.com/

Last, check whether you have correct api. The REST API to get a single work item is as below:

```
Get http://TFS2017:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=3.2
```

Attach a screenshot of the result in Postman:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Cece. After upgrading to PostMan v6.1.4 it worked. Url used was `http://tfs.blahblah.org:8080/TFS/MyOrgName/_apis/wit/workitems/12345?api-version=3.0` **Do you have a link to API documentation where I can do more fun stuff?**

Comment: You can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-4.1